# Concatenating a string to make up an SQL query in C

Tags: sql, c, casting

I need to do this in two separate steps but so far I am not finding a way of doing this.

First, I need to convert a double variable, into a char variable (and to be saved in that variable). I have noticed type casting doesnt work the same in C as Java / other languages. How do I cast a variable to be a string / char?

Second, I need to concatenate the strings, there will be a total of 6 string variables that will need concatenating, I have only found the `strcat` function which only takes 2 arguments.

These are the strings I am trying to build:

```
char *queryOne = "INSERT INTO location (id, carid, ownerid, lat, long, speed) VALUES (,2, 1, ";
char *queryTwo = lat; // lat is a double
char *queryThree = ",";
char *queryFour = longatude; // longatude is a double
char *queryFive = ",";
char *querySix = speed; // speed is a double
```

And then I need the concatenated string to work in: `(mysql_query(conn, query))` as one long string

Edit: So possibly, this should convert the datatype I think?

```
char buffer [50];

char *queryOne = "INSERT INTO location (id, carid, ownerid, lat, long, speed) VALUES (,2, 1, ";
char *queryTwo = sprintf (buffer, "%d", lat);
char *queryThree = ",";
char *queryFour = sprintf (buffer, "%d", longatude);
char *queryFive = ",";
char *querySix = sprintf (buffer, "%d", speed);

fprintf(stderr, "Dta: %s\n", queryOne);
fprintf(stderr, "Dta: %s\n", *queryTwo);
fprintf(stderr, "Dta: %s\n", queryThree);
fprintf(stderr, "Dta: %s\n", *queryFour);
fprintf(stderr, "Dta: %s\n", queryFive);
fprintf(stderr, "Dta: %s\n", *querySix);
```

Comment: Look at [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/).

Comment: Why do you need to do in two separate steps?

Comment: @JoeFarrell thanks, I have edited my post to use sprintf

Comment: @WeatherVane because I need to know how to convert to char from double, as I need one long string of chars to use with the SQL query

Comment: Does c not support query parameters?

Comment: @DanBracuk good suggestion, however https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx C is not on the list of supported languages there

Comment: What about this:  http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/intro_to_ado_in_c++.html ?

Comment: @DanBracuk that is for C++, whereas I need C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you could use:

```
#define MAXSQL 256
char sql[MAXSQL];
snprintf(sql, MAXSQL,  "%s %f , %f , %f", queryOne, lat, longatude, speed);
```

The `snprintf` function writes onto the buffer, that is its first argument. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/?kw=snprintf

Now you can use the `sql` string as you please.

Note that I used snprintf rather than sprintf. This is to avoid potential buffer overflows.

Also, don't use strcat so repeatedly, because that causes a Shlemiel the Painter algorithm, and every next call to strcat gets slower, because strcat has to start from the beginning and find the null terminator. See http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html for more info.

Comment: Don't use `%lf` for doubles in `printf` family. Use it for doubles in `scanf` family. Here `%f` is sufficient for `double`.

Comment: Changed as you said @WeatherVane

Comment: @cpp_prog thanks for the suggestion, is this what you mean? `mysql_query(conn, snprintf(sql, MAXSQL, "%s %f , %f , %f", queryOne, lat, longatude, speed))` as it is producing a segfault

Comment: No, you are passing the return value from `snprintf` which is its length. Make the string `sql` as advised, then `mysql_query(conn, sql)`. I respectfully advise to *read the manual*.

Comment: @WeatherVane ah sorry I didn't realise `sql` was to be used as a variable, I thought that was just a buffer size